# this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, angular, razorpay

I am working with Angular 4 , Project , I have to integrate razorpay in the project , It works fine in the test, dev environments but it throws an error in particular environment it throws the following error in live environment.

> vendor.cdeb9a8730a2fc78a675.bundle.js:1 ERROR TypeError:
>   this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay is not a constructor

**Code**

```
  rzp1:any; 
    this.rzp1 = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay(this.paymentOptions, successCallback, cancelCallback);
        this.rzp1.open(this.paymentOptions, successCallback, cancelCallback);
```

Window Ref Service

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function _window() : any {
   // return the global native browser window object
   return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRefService {
   get nativeWindow() : any {
      return _window();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Content Security Enabled**

Content security has been enabled for the particular domain it stops loading external js files , I asked server team to whitelist the Razorpay url (https://checkout.razorpay.com/v1/checkout.js), Then its Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working sample for beginers who are facing issue in initial steps in integrating it in angular:

**window-ref.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

function _window(): any {
  // return the global native browser window object
  return window;
}

@Injectable()
export class WindowRefService {

  constructor() { }

  get nativeWindow(): any {
      return _window();
  }
}
```

import it in app module and add in providers

```
import { WindowRefService } from '../Services/window-ref.service';

providers: [WindowRefService]
```

import it on the page you are going to use

```
import { WindowRefService } from '../Services/window-ref.service';
@Component({
  providers: [WindowRefService]
})

constructor(private winRef: WindowRefService) {}

const rzp = new this.winRef.nativeWindow.Razorpay
```